# Is it possible to check if a 7zip archive contains the same contents as a directory?

Tags: windows, backup, compression, 7-zip

I have a folder on my external hard drive for saving minor backups (`G:\LOG`), whose contents I have compressed as `G:\LOG\LOG.7z`. However, I am unsure as to if this was entirely succesful.
The folder is too large to check manually, so I wondered if it was possible to check if the files where the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can request a listing of the entire archive using the `l` argument. For example:

```
7z l archive.zip
```

You can then redirect that output to a text file, like so:

```
7z l archive.zip > xyzzy.txt
```

Comparing this output to a directory list should tell you if the archive matches or not.

Other than that you can also always compare the total size of the two folders.